# Redux-auth, fetch does not authenticate in dispatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux

I'm using [redux-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/redux-auth) for authentication in my application. Login and sign up is working great, but using the fetch function included does not authenticate the user. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Rails server output
Started GET "/users/me" for ::1 at 2016-08-04 20:42:00 +0200
Processing by UsersController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"me", "user"=>{}}
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.0ms)
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms (Views: 3.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

// User actions
export function fetchUser(id = 'me') {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestUser(id))

    return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}`, {
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json =>
        console.log(json)
        //dispatch(receiveUser(id, json))
      )
  }
}

// My component
...
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.loadSettings();
  }
...

UserSettings = reduxForm({
  form: 'user',
  fields: ['username', 'email']
},
state => ({
  initialValues: state.user.currentUser,
  user: state.user.currentUser
}),
{
  loadSettings: fetchUser
})(UserSettings)

export default UserSettings;
```

Comment: Do you see the network request in dev tools? Does the `json` get logged?

Comment: @DavidGilbertson The JSON is the error given by Rails, "Authorized users only." and if I turn off the check, it works. So the call is working, but I suspect the headers aren't actually sent. Edit: I'll check if that's what's happening tomorrow

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Apparently the token is undefined. In the headers there is "authorization: Bearer undefined"

Comment: Fetch doesn't send cookies by default, try putting `credentials: 'include'` in your [fetch options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch). Does that help?

Comment: Yes, but the token is not saved in the cookies. The authorization header is correctly included, but there's a problem with saving or retrieving it, apparently.

Comment: Do you maybe have to explicitly pass a header `"Authorization": "Bearer blahblahblah"`?

Comment: As stated in the previous comment, the authorization header is correctly passed, but incorrect (It's `Authorization: Bearer undefined`). I figure this is because I'm missing the server-side part of Redux-auth in my implementation.